# Code won't append data from a file to a list

Tags: python

For some reason I can't append the lines of my file to an empty list. "data1.txt" is just a file full of lines and lines of numbers. Calling this function returns an empty list.

```
filename = 'data1.txt'    
def get_data(filename):
        with open(filename, 'r') as qfile:
            data = qfile.read().splitlines()
            float_list = []
            for line in data:
                float_list.append(float(line))
            return float_list
```

Comment: How are you calling this code? `filename  = 'data1.txt'` isn't used, only the filename you pass into the function. Maybe you're pointing at the wrong file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> def get_data(filename):
...     with open(filename, 'r') as qfile:
...         return map(float, qfile)
```

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
filename = 'data1.txt'    
def get_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as qfile:
        float_list = []
        for line in qfile:
            float_list.append(float(line))

    return float_list
```

Note: you have a few problems in your code in terms of mixed indentation (spaces and tabs)